# Checking elements from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have two diferent arrays and I need to know if the name from the first array "date" is in the second array "name"

```
date = ['Olivia Smith', 'Jacob Williams', 'Jessica Taylor', 'Harry Miller']
name = ['Olivia', 'Jessica', 'Jacob', 'James']

for i in range(len(data)):
    x = 0
    print(name.index(data[x]))
    x = x + 1
    i = i + 1
```

I want the program to confirm that the name from the 'data' array is in the 'name' array

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Unmitigated I want the program to confirm that the name from the 'data' array is in the 'name' array

Comment: So you want to check that all values of date are in name or what? Also only the first name or last name as well?

Comment: Only if the name from 'data' is in the 'name' array, I don't care about the last name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So, what happens when you try running your code? What should happen instead, and how is that different? "I want the program to confirm that the name from the 'data' array is in the 'name' array" I don't understand why it should "confirm" that, because as far as I can tell, that isn't true. For example, when I consider the strings `'Olivia'`, `'Jessica'`, `'Jacob'`, and `'James'`, I don't think any of those is equal to `'Olivia Smith'`(or any of the other strings from the first list). Where am I wrong? (BTW: we call them **lists** in Python, not arrays.)

Comment: Are you trying to take [what appears to be] the forename from each full name in the *date* list and check if it's **anywhere** in the *name* list or just in the same relative position? Sample output would help to clarify your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension and `string.split()` to grab just the first names. Then use another list comprehension to grab the intersect.

```
date = ['Olivia Smith', 'Jacob Williams', 'Jessica Taylor', 'Harry Miller']
name = ['Olivia', 'Jessica', 'Jacob', 'James']

date_fn = [full_name.split()[0] for full_name in date]

names_in_both = [first_name for first_name in date_fn if first_name in name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split and grab the first part. then iterate and compare.

```py
new_date = [name.split(' ')[0] for name in date]

for name in set(name):
    if name in new_date:
        print(f"{name} is found!.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension:

```
out = [sum(x in y for y in date) for x in name]
print(*zip(name, out), sep='\n')

# Ouput:
('Olivia', 1)
('Jessica', 1)
('Jacob', 1)
('James', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that any one exists (returns bool):

```
any(i.split()[0] in name for i in date)
```

If you want to check that all exist (returns bool):

```
any(i.split()[0] in name for i in date)
```

If you want to retrieve the ones that exist:

```
def intersection(a, b):
    res = []
    for i in a:
        if i.split()[0] in b:
            res.append(i.split()[0])
    return res
print(intersection(date, name))
# Output: ['Olivia', 'Jacob', 'Jessica']
```

You can simplify the above function to:

```
def intersection(a, b):
    res = [i.split()[0] for i in a if i.split()[0] in b]
    return res
```

Docs:
[`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)
[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)
[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)